# How to print variable from hooked native function in Android using Frida

Tags: reverse-engineering, frida

I have an android app which loads a `mylib.so`. This library has a function called `decryptChar` which I want to hook and print a string variable calculated in there. I am using [frida](https://www.frida.re/) for this purpose. I have made some attempts but given my inexperience in this everything is a fail. I would like to print the variable `Key` just before leaving the function so I could get the final value of it.

A code I have used is the following

```
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName("mylib.so", "decryptChar"), {
    onEnter: function (args) {
        console.log(this.Key.value);
    }
});
```

What is a proper way of doing this?

Comment: Anyone to know how to answer this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't print local variable. You should hook the use site of the variable. If the variable is used in a **another function call** in `decryptChar`, you should hook the function. If you want to see what function is called to the variable as argument in `decryptChar`, it is good to use disassembler like ida pro because the function you want to hook is defined in `.so` library.

For example, a `write()` function is called with the variable as argument from `decryptChar()`, you hook the `write()` function call. Then, you could print the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed couple of things

onLeave argument is the return value, the `this` is used to pass data from onEnter

If you want to print the first argument for static method, lets assume it's a pointer to string

```js
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName("mylib.so", "decryptChar"), {
    onEnter: function (args) {
        console.log(args[0].readCString());
    }
});
```

Read the docs @ https://www.frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#instruction

Comment: yes indeed `onLeave` is used incorrectly. Though i want to print a variable not an argument and using the  `.value` as mentioned in the docs did not work